# iOS aspect fit and center

Tags: ios, uiview

I'd like to call

`[self.view setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit | UIViewContentModeCenter];`

where `self` is an instance of `UIViewController`. This doesn't seem to work; what are the direct alternatives, if any?

Comment: why do you say that it does not work? what is the content of the view that you expect to be scaled?

Comment: did you get alternative answer for your problem?

Comment: @Miraaj jtbandes corrected my misunderstanding at the time.

Comment: I solved this problem. Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/28957516/4057176

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `contentMode` is not a mask; you can't use `|` to combine values, you'll have to pick one. `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` should center the content if it doesn't fit the view.

Comment: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit does not center the image.

Comment: @CodeMonkey check my recent answer

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set contentMode once when the view loads and then center it in viewWillLayoutSubviews which is called upon device rotation.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  //additional code to instantiate and setup image
  imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
  self.view.addSubview(profileImageView)
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    imageView.center.x = view.center.x
    //or imageView.center = view.center
    //or imageView.center.y = view.center.y
}
```

Comment: how does this work when trying to center an image in thumbView on a cell?

Comment: This is probably a new question

Comment: Add a new question and link me