# UIImageView aspect fit and center

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an image view, declared programmatically, and I am setting its image, also programmatically.

However, I find myself unable to set the image to both fit the aspect and align centre to the image view.

In other words, I want the image to:

- Scale down to fit the aspect, if the image is large.
- Centre but not scale up, if the image is small.

How do I get that?

Comment: [yourImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter]; and make sure if imageView Frame is greater than image frame. if it's not then place [yourImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeAspectToFit];

Comment: if else condition dude @RyanPoolos

Answer (score 216):

Just pasting the solution:

Just like @manohar said

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
if (imageView.bounds.size.width > ((UIImage*)imagesArray[i]).size.width && imageView.bounds.size.height > ((UIImage*)imagesArray[i]).size.height) {
       imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
}
```

solved my problem

Comment: Shorter way to find out image is smaller: `CGRectContainsRect(imageView.bounds, {CGPointZero, image.size})`

Comment: @Cfr maybe it's shorter, but not so readable. At the same time I propose to split line with if-statement like this: `CGSize imageSize = ((UIImage*)imagesArray[i]).size;`, `CGSize viewSize = imageView.bounds.size`, `if (viewSize.width > imageSize.width && viewSize.height > imageSize.height) {`.

Comment: Should be UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit

Comment: imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

Answer (score 83):

In swift language we can set content mode of UIImage view like following as:

```
let newImgThumb = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))
newImgThumb.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Comment: This blows up the image if it is smaller than the image view, contrary to what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 40):

### Swift

```
yourImageView.contentMode = .center
```

You can use the following options to position your image:

- `scaleToFill`
- `scaleAspectFit`   // contents scaled to fit with fixed
  aspect. remainder is transparent
- `redraw` // redraw on bounds change (calls -setNeedsDisplay)
- `center` // contents remain same size. positioned adjusted.
- `top`
- `bottom`
- `left`
- `right`
- `topLeft`
- `topRight`
- `bottomLeft`
- `bottomRight`

Answer (score 12):

**Updated answer**

When I originally answered this question in 2014, there was no requirement to not scale the image up in the case of a small image. (The question was [edited in 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15499376/revisions).) If you have such a requirement, you will indeed need to compare the image's size to that of the imageView and use either `UIViewContentModeCenter` (in the case of an image smaller than the imageView) or `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` in all other cases.

**Original answer**

Setting the imageView's contentMode to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` was enough for me. It seems to center the images as well. I'm not sure why others are using logic based on the image. See also this question: [iOS aspect fit and center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049105/ios-aspect-fit-and-center)

Comment: This blows up the image if it is smaller than the image view, contrary to what the OP asked for.

Comment: @fishinear The requirement about not scaling the image up was added to the question a year after I answered it: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15499376/revisions

Answer (score 10):

I solved this problem like this.

1. setImage to `UIImageView` (with `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`)
2. get imageSize `(CGSize imageSize = imageView.image.size)`
3. `UIImageView` resize. `[imageView sizeThatFits:imageSize]`
4. move position where you want.

I wanted to put UIView on the top center of `UICollectionViewCell`.
so, I used this function.

```
- (void)setImageToCenter:(UIImageView *)imageView
{
    CGSize imageSize = imageView.image.size;
    [imageView sizeThatFits:imageSize];
    CGPoint imageViewCenter = imageView.center;
     imageViewCenter.x = CGRectGetMidX(self.contentView.frame);
    [imageView setCenter:imageViewCenter];
}
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve this by setting content mode of image view to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill.

Then use following method method to get the resized uiimage object.

```
- (UIImage*)setProfileImage:(UIImage *)imageToResize onImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView
{
    CGFloat width = imageToResize.size.width;
    CGFloat height = imageToResize.size.height;
    float scaleFactor;
    if(width > height)
    {
        scaleFactor = imageView.frame.size.height / height;
    }
    else
    {
        scaleFactor = imageView.frame.size.width / width;
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(width * scaleFactor, height * scaleFactor), NO, 0.0);
    [imageToResize drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, width * scaleFactor, height * scaleFactor)];
    UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return resizedImage;
}
```

Edited Here (Swift Version)

```
func setProfileImage(imageToResize: UIImage, onImageView: UIImageView) -> UIImage
{
    let width = imageToResize.size.width
    let height = imageToResize.size.height

    var scaleFactor: CGFloat

    if(width > height)
    {
        scaleFactor = onImageView.frame.size.height / height;
    }
    else
    {
        scaleFactor = onImageView.frame.size.width / width;
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(width * scaleFactor, height * scaleFactor), false, 0.0)
    imageToResize.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, width * scaleFactor, height * scaleFactor))
    let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return resizedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This subclass uses center if the image is not larger than the view, otherwise it scales down. I found this useful for a `UIImageView` that changes the size.

The image it displays is smaller than the view for large sizes, but larger than the view for small sizes. I want it only to scale down, but not up.

```
class CenterScaleToFitImageView: UIImageView {
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            adjustContentMode()
        }
    }

    override var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            adjustContentMode()
        }
    }

    func adjustContentMode() {
        guard let image = image else {
            return
        }
        if image.size.width > bounds.size.width ||
            image.size.height > bounds.size.height {
            contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        } else {
            contentMode = .Center
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
let bannerImageView = UIImageView();
bannerImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit;
bannerImageView.frame = CGRectMake(cftX, cftY, ViewWidth, scrollHeight);
```

Comment: This blows up the image if it is smaller than the image view, contrary to what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 4):

```
[your_imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
```

Comment: This will ignore the scaling

Comment: I don't know why solutions like this got so many upvotes. This person clearly didn't read the question at all.

Answer (score 2):

For people looking for UIImage resizing,

```
@implementation UIImage (Resize)

- (UIImage *)scaledToSize:(CGSize)size
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0f);
    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}

- (UIImage *)aspectFitToSize:(CGSize)size
{
    CGFloat aspect = self.size.width / self.size.height;
    if (size.width / aspect <= size.height)
    {
        return [self scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(size.width, size.width / aspect)];
    } else {
        return [self scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(size.height * aspect, size.height)];
    }
}

- (UIImage *)aspectFillToSize:(CGSize)size
{
    CGFloat imgAspect = self.size.width / self.size.height;
    CGFloat sizeAspect = size.width/size.height;

    CGSize scaledSize;

        if (sizeAspect > imgAspect) { // increase width, crop height
            scaledSize = CGSizeMake(size.width, size.width / imgAspect);
        } else { // increase height, crop width
            scaledSize = CGSizeMake(size.height * imgAspect, size.height);
        }
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0f);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClipToRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height));
    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, scaledSize.width, scaledSize.height)];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}

@end
```