# How do I make image-based tiled background for UIView so that it doesn't scale?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

In iOS application, I have 250x85pt UIView. I would like it to have image-based tiled background. The original image is 398x398 px. I would like my image to tile.

[image]

When I run application, my image tiles, but for some reason it scales as follows:

[image]

I used the following code to achieve it:

```
var image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "myfilepath.png")!
var uicolor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
uiview.backgroundColor = uicolor
```

Could you explain 
1. why ios scales my image, and
2. how do I draw tiled image without scaling?

Comment: Please don't name your `var` "uicolor"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

basically the image is bigger than your `UIView`. when you give `UIColor(patternImage: image)` it uses 1x size of the image. 
The image we  usually laptops are scaled to window size with its aspect ratio.

So scale your image to your requirement and then apply it as background image.

Comment: The problem is that images I have are user-uploaded. Is there way to adjust it somehow from code?

Comment: @AlexSmolov it would be recommended to use `UIImageView` and set `ContentMode` to ` UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`

Comment: @AlexSmolov this question and its answers will be helpful to you i guess
[UIImageView aspect fit and center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499376/uiimageview-aspect-fit-and-center)

Comment: Thanks, but in addition to that I need my pattern to tile.

Comment: reduce the size of the image and then apply it as a background pattern.
[resuce image size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612131/whats-the-easiest-way-to-resize-optimize-an-image-size-with-the-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 6):

To expand on Banto's answer, the issue is that your view is 250x85 points, which, on retina devices is really 500x170 pixels.  When your x1 image is turned into a pattern it is applied at the point level.  The problem can be easily changed by setting the scale on the image to match the scale on the device:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 85))

let image = UIImage(named: "myfilepath.png")!
let scaled = UIImage(CGImage: image.CGImage, scale: UIScreen.mainScreen().scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)

view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: scaled!)
```

Comment: Thank you, David! I found out that if you add @3x (as in "myfilepath@3x.png") to the image name, it will work perfectly on every device.

Comment: I'd suggest 2x at that point, but yeah, that's doing pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 self.mainView.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"CROPNET.png"].CGImage;
```