# UICollectionView image getting stretched

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

My `UICollectionView` is stretching the images inside the cells.How to fit the image inside the cell?

Comment: share your image setting code ???

Comment: check this ... http://blogs.innovationm.com/image-handling-in-ios/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following for setting content mode of `UIImage`

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Comment: Is it possible to center crop the image? Now it shows kind of zoomed out.

Comment: yes.. use UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill instead of UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit but you also need to set imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

Comment: Great. Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

For center cropping of image

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

you can also try this solution to best fit your need

[Image with aspect fit and center cropping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499376/uiimageview-aspect-fit-and-center)